# SSIS and 64bit excel

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2010, ssis

I have researched this thoroughly but I've yet to find a satisfactory answer.

I am using SQL Server Data Tools 2010 and Microsoft Office 2013 64-bit. I know that there is a compatibility problem and I am trying to solve it because I know for a fact that you can use an .xlsx file as a data source in a Data Flow.

First I tried setting Run64BitRuntime to False in Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties - > Debugging but it didn't work

Whenever I try importing an .xlsx file I get the same error

```
 Microsoft Visual Studio
------------------------------

Could not retrieve the table information for the connection manager
'Source Path'. Failed to connect to the source using the connection
manager 'Source Path'

------------------------------
```

So I tried downloading the "Microsoft Access database engine 2010" as so many suggested. The 64-bit installed successfully but the 32-bit returned the following error

```
You cannot install the 32-bit version of Microsoft Access database engine 2010
because you currently have 64-bit Office products installed.
```

Now I know I am missing a step here cause while I can see "Microsoft Access database engine 2010" in the list of installed programs in control panel it does not show up as an option in the Provider list when I am trying to create a new Connection Manager.

So before I result following the instruction on this [blog](http://hrvoje.piasevoli.com/2010/09/01/importing-data-from-64-bit-excel-in-ssis/)  I would like to ensure there is no easier way of solving the problem

Thank you in advance for you time.

Comment: Because Visual Studio is 32bit you need 32bit office/excel drivers. And because you can't install both 32bit and 64bit drivers you got a problem. Solutions:
-Use a regular 32bit office (or even better don't use office on a machine with SQL Server)
-Don't use excel as a source in SSIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the answer was so ridiculously easy that I kind of feel ashamed for this post now.

If you are using Microsoft Office 2013 64-bit and want to work with SSIS you have to download and install the **32-bit** [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255), not the 64-bit, set Run64BitRuntime to False and everything will work like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

If you're machine is x64, forget about Excel, as there is no driver available. 
Just convert the file to CSV and use a Flat File Connector instead.